# git feature-branch workflow

Tags: git, workflow, branch, release

I'm trying to implement the workflow as described by Adam Dymitruk (http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/).

What I like about this approach is the independence of the feature branches. Only code relevant to the feature is present in this branch. During a sprint it's possible to freely compose a release branch based on the different feature branches. Adam has answered some questions already but I'm struggling with a couple of things.

From what I've found, the release and integration(dev) branch are long running and can be reset when necessary? Dev's continuously merge from their feature branch to the integration branch. Completed features are merged to the release branch.

- Since the release and integration branch are shared (pushed up), what happens when they get reset? How should the other dev's deal with this? The release branch is supposed to be recomposed when you want to take a feature out. Do you need to delete the old release branch on the remote first and do the other dev's also need to delete their release branches first? This seems cumbersome.
- Is it better not to have a long running release branch but create a whole bunch of different ones?

So basically, how can freely recomposing a branch (and thus rewriting history) work with sharing this branch among dev's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be using this workflow, might I recommend [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)?

If you use a gatekeeper like this, the result of merging a particular feature with the integration branch gets tested *before* it gets merged in. So you only need to "rewind" the integration branch if a feature which made its way through code review and verification is later discarded. In this case, the use of `git revert` would be appropriate - so the integration branch does not actually move backward, it just gains an "inverted" commit to remove the feature.

The release branch can handle things the same way.

Another option is to just have a different name for each release/feature branch. When you need to remove something, you create a new `integration-201301` branch and stop working on the older one. Other devs can delete their copies of the past branch(es) at their leisure. Since the branch which is the same as the old one minus a feature is an entirely new composition with a different name, no history needs to be rewritten.

Comment: I'm familiar with Gerrit and it's too much overhead for our needs. I trust the devs to only merge good features. Different names seems like a reasonable solution, although it's not as 'clean' as I would like. I don't think there is any other way. If you change the history of a shared branch you will get in trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @Ivo You don't have to actually change the history. As I noted, `git revert` has the effect of "removing" the feature without altering history.